# dφ is bijective but φ is not a lie group isomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-isomorphism

suppose G and H connected Lie groups. Is there $\phi: G \to H$ a morphism of Lie groups such that $d\phi$ is bijective but $\phi$ is not an isomorphism of Lie groups?

I know that $d\phi$ surjective and H connected $\Rightarrow \phi$ surjective. And I know that $d\phi$ injective $\Rightarrow Ker \phi$ is discrete.

So to come up with a potential example, I need to prove that $Ker\phi$ could be non trivial. Is that a possibility?

Many thanks for your hints or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the natural map. Then $d\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the identity.

Comment: Thank you! Please correct me if I am wrong: $d\phi: Lie(\Bbb R) \to Lie(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)$. I understand that $Lie(\Bbb R)\cong T\Bbb R = \Bbb R $ but is  $Lie(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z) \cong T(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z) = \Bbb R$?

Comment: @PerelMan yes. The metaphor is that the tangent space at the identity is located infinitesimally at zero so it can't "see" that you've killed $1$ which is far away, so the tangent spaces are just the same. More rigorously, if you think of a tangent vector as something that eats germs of smooth functions, a smooth function in a neighborhood of $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is the same thing as a smooth function in a neighborhood of $0$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ once the neighborhood gets small enough.

Comment: Great explanation and metaphor! many thanks @hunter